# How to insert a list to dataframe using different forms?

Tags: python, list, pandas

How to transform the elements in the list and insert to dataframe ?

It's my data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['country','date','value'])
data = ['Japan',(t1,123), (t2,456), (t3,789)]
```

It's my expected result :

```
    country  date  value
0   'Japan'   t1    123
1   'Japan'   t2    456
2   'Japan'   t3    789
```

Thanks your help !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Plan**

- I want to zip the all column names from the second one on with the relevant components in the list of tuples.  I can pass this to `dict` and get

  ```
  dict(zip(df.columns[1:], zip(*data[1:])))

  {'date': ('t1', 't2', 't3'), 'value': (123, 456, 789)}
  ```
- By unpacking this I can pass the resulting key/value pairs to `pd.DataFrame.assign` and get

  ```
  df.assign(**dict(zip(df.columns[1:], zip(*data[1:]))))

    country date  value
  0     NaN   t1    123
  1     NaN   t2    456
  2     NaN   t3    789
  ```
- I'm just missing my country and since I've already established an index with the length of the other columns, I can pass a scalar value to `pd.DataFrame.assign` for the finishing touch

---

**Solution**

```
df.assign(**dict(zip(df.columns[1:], zip(*data[1:])))).assign(country=data[0])

  country date  value
0   Japan   t1    123
1   Japan   t2    456
2   Japan   t3    789
```

---

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['country', 'date', 'value'])
data = ['Japan', ('t1', 123), ('t2', 456), ('t3', 789)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

dict ={"country":["Japan","Japan","Japan"],
       "date":["t1","t2","t3"],
       "value":[123,456,789]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
print(df)
```